# Configure openvpn for ExpressVPN TCP ports

Tags: tcp, openvpn, udp

I want to use the `openvpn` client on my Ubuntu 20.10 to connect to ExpressVPN's VPN.

Unfortunately I have to use the TCP ports, as the UDP ports are blocked.

ExpressVPN's website only allows to download configuration files for UDP port.

How can I convert the configuration file to use TCP ports?

Here is the file, with subscription information abridged.

```
dev tun
fast-io
persist-key
persist-tun
nobind
remote <ABRIDGED>.com 1195

remote-random
pull
comp-lzo no
tls-client
verify-x509-name Server name-prefix
ns-cert-type server
key-direction 1
route-method exe
route-delay 2
tun-mtu 1500
fragment 1300
mssfix 1200
verb 3
cipher AES-256-CBC
keysize 256
auth SHA512
sndbuf 524288
rcvbuf 524288
auth-user-pass

<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
<ABRIDGED>
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
<ABRIDGED>
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
<ABRIDGED>
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
<ca>
<ABRIDGED>
</ca>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. In `remote <ABRIDGED>.com 1195`, change the port number from 1195 to 443
2. Add `proto tcp-client` to a new line
3. Remove `fragment 1300` and `comp-lzo no`

Comment: It does not work for me, server always closes the TCP connection: Connection reset, restarting [0]
Tested with 5.157.128.13.